# How to go to main file on error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I often get errors along the lines of

```
Error   1   error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated (..\XXX\yyy.cpp) c:\...\msvc\boost_1_55_0\include\boost-1_55\boost\thread\future.hpp 332 1   xxx

1>c:\...\msvc\boost_1_55_0\include\boost-1_55\boost\thread\future.hpp(332): warning C4913: user defined binary operator ',' exists but no overload could convert all operands, default built-in binary operator ',' used (..\XXXX\yyy.cpp)
```

If I double click it, it always opens the header file with the actual error. But I'd rather it open the compiled file yyy.cpp. Is there a way of doing so?